# Rails 3.0.9 : ActiveRecord Uniqueness Constraint failing on every updated, doesn't matter if the unique column isn't touched

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Profile model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :user_id, :race_id, :nickname, :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :birth_date, :eighteen,
            :time_zone, :metric_scale, :referral_code, :referrer_id, :tag_line

  # Relationships
  belongs_to  :user
  belongs_to  :race
  belongs_to :referred_by, :class_name => "Profile", :foreign_key => "referral_code"
  has_many :referrals, :class_name => "Profile", :foreign_key => "referrer_id"

  # Validations
  validates :user_id, :race_id, :nickname, :first_name, :last_name, :time_zone, :gender, :presence => true
  validates :referral_code, :nickname, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  # Instance Methods
  def full_name
    first_name + " " + last_name
  end

  # Class Methods
  def self.search(search)
    search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
    find(:all, :conditions => ['nickname LIKE ?', search_condition])
  end

  def self.find_by_referral_code(referrer_code)
    find(:one, :conditions => ['referral_code LIKE ?', referrer_code])
  end

end
```

No matter which column I am updated the Uniqueness Constraint on 'referral_code' false and I cannot update the model and I can't figure out why. From what I read online as of Rails 3 ActiveRecord was supposed to be tracking dirty objects and only generating update queries containing the altered columns leaving all others alone. Because it should only be performing update queries on columns other than the Unique ones the validation should not be failing. Unfortunately it is. Here is Rails Console session displaying this:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.9)
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > profile = Profile.find(3)
 => #<Profile id: 3, user_id: 3, race_id: 2, nickname: "Premium-User", first_name: "Premium", last_name: "User", gender: "M", birth_date: "1977-01-01", eighteen: true, complete: true, time_zone: "Kuala Lumpur", metric_scale: false, referral_code: "bo", referrer_id: nil, tag_line: "This is what its like.", created_at: "2011-09-21 04:08:00", updated_at: "2011-09-21 04:08:00"> 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > update = {"tag_line"=>"Changed to this"}
 => {"tag_line"=>"Changed to this"} 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > profile.update_attributes(update)
 => false 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > profile.errors
 => {:referral_code=>["has already been taken"]}
```

Even performing an update directly on a single column which is not unique causes the uniqueness constraint to fail and the record will not be updated, here is a console session:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.9)
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > profile = Profile.find(3)
 => #<Profile id: 3, user_id: 3, race_id: 2, nickname: "Premium-User", first_name: "Premium", last_name: "User", gender: "M", birth_date: "1977-01-01", eighteen: true, complete: true, time_zone: "Kuala Lumpur", metric_scale: false, referral_code: "bo", referrer_id: nil, tag_line: "This is what its like.", created_at: "2011-09-21 04:08:00", updated_at: "2011-09-21 04:08:00"> 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > profile.tag_line = "changed to this"
 => "changed to this" 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > profile.save
 => false 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > profile.errors
 => {:referral_code=>["has already been taken"]}
```

I also ran a check to see if ActiveRecord was actually tracking the dirty object and it appears to be, here is the console session:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.9)
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > profile = Profile.find(3)
 => #<Profile id: 3, user_id: 3, race_id: 2, nickname: "Premium-User", first_name: "Premium", last_name: "User", gender: "M", birth_date: "1977-01-01", eighteen: true, complete: true, time_zone: "Kuala Lumpur", metric_scale: false, referral_code: "bo", referrer_id: nil, tag_line: "This is what its like.", created_at: "2011-09-21 04:08:00", updated_at: "2011-09-21 04:08:00"> 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > profile.tag_line = "change to this"
 => "change to this" 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > profile.changes
 => {"tag_line"=>["This is what its like.", "change to this"]} 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > profile.save
 => false 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > profile.errors
 => {:referral_code=>["has already been taken"]}
```

I honestly am at a loss, I have spent quite a bit of time digging into it as well as searching Google and I cannot find an answer as to why this is happening.

Comment: What do you get from Profile.find_all_by_referral_code(profile.referral_code) ?

Comment: Is this contraint also implemented at the database level? Dump the DDL for that table and check to see if there are any keys/constraints there. Also check log/development.log to get the actual SQL query the update is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, Rails does only "track" the dirty columns and generates the minimum update statement necessary.  If you look in your log/development.log file you will see the actual SQL that is being generated, and you'll see that the update statement is only touching the columns you have edited.  At least you would if your code was getting that far.

Before saving your model, Rails will run all the validations on it, and that includes seeing if the referral code is unique.  To do this it will run a select SQL statement against the database to check; if you look in the development.log file you will definitely see this query.

So Rails is working correctly here.

If your referral codes are supposed to be unique, why aren't they?  My guess would be that you are trying to save models with a nil or blank code.  If that is the case, try adding `:allow_nil => true` or `:allow_blank => true` to the :uniqueness hash.